# How to list Add items to Sharepoint list using .asmx web service

Tags: c#, winforms, list, sharepoint-2010, asmx

I have used asmx web service in my project. I want to add items to existing SharePoint list.

```
   mylist.Url = Url.TrimEnd('/') + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
            mylist.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            XmlNode node = mylist.GetList(_listName);
```

And I have store my values in DataTable. How can I directly add data to SharePoint list from C# Datatable?
Or should I convert it to Xml and add ?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms440289.aspx) for the general usage of `UpdateListItems`, although it only has an example for updating items.

Then look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems.aspx) for an example of the XML you need to send to create a *new* item rather than updating an existing one.

You'll need to loop through your data table constructing an XML structure for each item you want to add, but you can then add them all in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to consume SharePoint Web Services, in particular [Lists Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists(v=office.12).aspx) to create a List Item:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace SharePoint.Client
{
    public class ListsClient : IDisposable
    {
        public ListsClient(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials)
        {
            _client = new Lists.Lists();
            _client.Credentials = credentials;
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }

        public ListsClient(Uri webUri)
        {
            _client = new Lists.Lists();
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Create a List Item 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listName">List Name</param>
        /// <param name="propertyValues">List Item properties</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public XmlNode CreateListItem(string listName,Dictionary<string,string> propertyValues)
        {
            var payload = new XmlDocument();
            var updates = payload.CreateElement("Batch");
            updates.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            var method = payload.CreateElement("Method");
            method.SetAttribute("ID", "1");
            method.SetAttribute("Cmd", "New");
            foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
            {
                var field = payload.CreateElement("Field");
                field.SetAttribute("Name", propertyValue.Key);
                field.InnerText = propertyValue.Value;
                method.AppendChild(field);
            }
            updates.AppendChild(method);
            return _client.UpdateListItems(listName, updates);
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        protected Lists.Lists _client;  //SharePoint Web Services Lists proxy

    }
}
```

**Usage**

How to create a Task item:

```
using (var client = new SPOListsClient(webUrl, userName, password))
{
    var taskProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    taskProperties["Title"] = "Order approval";
    taskProperties["Priority"] = "(2) Normal";
    var result = client.CreateListItem(listTitle, taskProperties);    
}
```

### References

- [SharePoint 2007 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Lists.UpdateListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)